# Relationship between vectors and matrices in R?

Tags: r, matrix, vector

In R, I've heard that vectors are a "fundamental" way of organizing information, in that many other things are defined in terms of vectors, but vectors are not defined in terms of many other things.  Are matrices similarly fundamental?  And is there a relationship between matrices and vectors (maybe R is like C#, in that a matrix is just a vector with one tiny instruction added?)

Comment: see details in `?array`

Comment: Yes, a matrix is a vector with dimensions.  But don't rely on `is.vector()` to tell you so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrices (see `?matrix` and the more general `?array`) are vectors binded together row-wise or column wise.

```
m <- matrix(0, 2, 2)
m
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
```

Not surprisingly, `m` is a `matrix`:

```
is.matrix(m)      # you can also try is.vector(m)
[1] TRUE
```

But a single column (or row) is no longer a `matrix` and, in a way, we "come back" to the `vector` class.

```
is.vector(m[, 1]) # you can also try is.matrix(m[, 1])
[1] TRUE
```

So the `matrix` class is "dropped" when extracting a single row/column. If you want ot preserve it you still can:

```
m[, 1, drop=FALSE]
```

This is useful e.g. in cases where you want to preserve the `apply` compatibility and when the number of rows/columns extracted may be of length 1. For instance subsetting a matrix based on a condition or whatever:

```
# this returns an error as m[, 1] is no longer a matrix
apply(m[, 1], 1, length)
Error in apply(m[, 1], 1, length) : dim(X) must have a positive length

# but this works like a charm
apply(m[, 1, drop=FALSE], 1, length)
[1] 1 1
```

Finally, there are finer-grained classes of vectors, called 'atomic' (see `?vector`) and they are returned by `class`:

```
class(m[, 1])
[1] "numeric"

class(m[, 1]>1)
[1] "logical"
```

And as seen above:

```
class(m[, 1, drop=FALSE])
[1] "matrix"
```